# Short(er) hand for min max percentage?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function that converts two values to a percentage within a range, in this case between 15000 and 100000. It feels very clunky. Is there a more simple way to express this which is easy/easier to understand?

```
price2percent = (sale) => {
    let price = sale.soldPrice / sale.livingArea;
    // Specifically these values
    price = price > 100000 ? 100000 : price;
    price = price < 15000 ? 15000 : price;

    return (price - 1500) / 85000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `Math.min` and `Math.max` to constrain the ranges:

```
const adjustedPrice = Math.min(
  100000,                // can be no higher than 100000
  Math.max(price, 15000) // can be no lower than 15000
);
return (adjustedPrice - 1500) / 85000;
```

Another option is nested conditionals, which will reduce the number of unnecessary reassignments, though it doesn't exactly make the code *clearer*:

```
const adjustedPrice =
  price > 100000 ? 100000 :
    price < 15000 ? 15000 : price
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this utility for things like that:

```
const clamp = (value, min, max) => value > min? value < max? value: max: min;

price2percent = (sale) => {
    let price = clamp(sale.soldPrice / sale.livingArea, 15000, 100000);    
    return (price - 1500) / 85000;
}
```

I find that more readable than the `Math.min(max, Math.max(min, value))` construct.

Downside, in its current version it doesn't play well with `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a more simple way to express this which is easy/easier to understand?

Easy to understand would be using if/else condition:

```
price2percent = (sale) => {
  let price = sale.soldPrice / sale.livingArea;
  if(price > 100000) price = 100000
  else if(price < 15000) price = 15000
  return (price - 1500) / 85000;
}
```

Which can be expressed shorter as: (the harder way)

```
price2percent = (sale) => {
  let price = sale.soldPrice / sale.livingArea;
  price = price > 100000 ? 100000 : (price < 15000 ? 15000 : price)
  return (price - 1500) / 85000;
}
```